# Installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on NVME disk and then previous Ubuntu on SSD disk won't start

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu

Previous installation wont boot into desktop. The latest installation was done from a USB stick using boot option in BIOS saying UEFI for the USB stick

Both Ubuntu installations are Kubuntu 22.04.1.

Result of update-grub:

```
sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda2
Found Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid on /dev/sdc2
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Comment: Is install on sda2? What brand/model system? What video card/chiip? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I followed your advice, here is the summary. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PfJrmZVD8M/

Comment: For the exact brand/model and video, I have to check that in the morning. But system has an Intel cpu running at 4.5ghz and using the built in graphics.

Comment: Its 11th Gen Intel. Not sure what brand uses AMI UEFI/BIOS. You show 3 UEFI installs and one old BIOS/MBR install of Windows. But broken BIOS grub in MBR of Windows drive. You might install Windows boot loader in BIOS mode & even have that boot, but have to change boot mode from UEFI to BIOS. Debian on sdc2 is booting from ESP on sdb1. Ubuntu UEFI entry is using invalid partUUID. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode in UEFI boot mode, choose prefered Ubuntu and ESP and do total reinstall of grub & latest kernel.

Comment: Its Gigabyte motherboard. Didn't know there was Windows leftovers, it will be purged away so not important. To take Windows out of the picture, I disabled the port for that disk and ran BootRepair again and used advanced options repair. Kernel replacement was not suggested. Reboted but earlier Ubuntu 22.04 is still not coming up. Last message is "sda clean". Btw, whats up with invalid partUUID that you mentioned? At some point yesterday I saw "mount: /boot/efi: Cant find UUID=9CA9-808F" and thats where my old Ubuntu is located.

Comment: Still working on it. Here are two more pastebins with information. https://pastebin.com/t5KB6Xfp and https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cwGhRZqPqF/

Comment: Sorry not looked into your details: are you certain your hardware allows access to both disk channels some setups are either-or as there's only one underlying channel.

Comment: Yes, I think so, look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/` there is a file called `fstab`. It contained the wrong
UUID for SDA1: `UUID=9CA9-808F`. That UUID doesn't match any of the disks in the computer. After replacing it with the SDA1 UUID reported by the Gnome Disk utility (`82DB-C613`) the computer booted normally as before the installation of Ubuntu 22.04.1. Boot-repair did not fix the issue.

It would be interesting to know how `UUID=9CA9-808F` got into the `fstab` file despite no disk having that ID. A bug in the Ubuntu installation process?